# Setup the two servers with different IP and apply the single domain

Tags: nginx, azure, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I'd like to setup the two servers with different IP and apply the single domain.

**Server 1**

Vendor: Azure
OS : Windows 2019
App : MVC application

We have Virtual Machine in Azure and running Windows Server. Few apps are hosted in IIS and used as the company production website. Contains the static pages, dynamic pages too

**Server 2 (Will create soon)**

Vendor : Azure
OS : Linux
App : Wordpress

We would like to move the static pages to CMS like WordPress to create the page quickly instead of creating from scratch. But, we will continue the dynamic modules like Support, Sales, Orders, Subscription in our MVC application from Server 1.

In this case, if some access the different URL it should server from the different server
www.example.com –  Server 1
www.example.com/sales  – Server 1
www.example.com/products - Server 2
www.example.com/products/aa - Server 2

Note: domain alone is the same. But the URL is not common for both servers.

Comment: you can do this using an IIS plugin called application request routing, it's L7 load balancing, you are routing by path. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Answer (score 0):

Note I would never do this with a production site however if I was going to do something like this I would use IPs.

For example-

Map DNS to the server IP of Server 1:

www.example.com – Server 1

www.example.com/sales – Server 1

Then within your application use the IP of server 2 for:

www.example.com/products - Server 2

www.example.com/products/aa - Server 2

It might be a little more work depending on if you are using relative or absolute urls, depending on your Notepad++ skills should be pretty easy to change.

On server 2 make sure you are using vhosts within your httpd.conf or hosting only 1 site to keep the domain default.

Im not 100% sure if a rewrite would work however if you are looking to keep the url example.com and not 123.456.123.332 iframes might be the way to go.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have something like a reverse proxy in front of your two servers to direct the traffic to the appropriate location. Azure Application Gateway will do this, allow you to route to different locations based on path rules.

[image]

It's not the cheapest method, and it has its own issues, but it will provide what you want. See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal) for more details.

You can also look at other opensource applications like Nginx, HAProxy etc.